# How do you add an annotated thumbnail link over a youtube video?

Tags: youtube, annotations

Check out 0:31 in the link below and you will see a thumbnail link in the lower right corner that clicks through to another video. How did they do this? I know how to add annotations but I'm curious how they were able to use what appears to be a dynamic thumbnail.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJIzSKpKZh0&list=PL41F53F1EF7A5E42A&index=4

Any help or leads appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was much easier than I thought. YouTube calls this InVideo Programming. To do this log into your youtube account and click the arrow next you your profile icon to reveal "YouTube Settings" and click it. Then on the left hand side under "Channel Settings" click "InVideo Programming". You can then feature your channel or feature a specific video on all of videos. Hopefully this helps someone!